# No metadata files found for isopack

Tags: meteor, meteor-mobile

whenever i run any meteor command like

> meteor run android-device

it is giving this error

> > C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
> >           throw error;
> >           ^
>
> Error: No metadata files found for isopack at:
>   /C/Users/abc/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.2_4
>       at Isopack._loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:900:13)

i have tried to uninstall and reinstall meteor again, also tried to update version but fails completely.

Comment: I solved that issue in past by uninstall meteor, and remove the .metoer folder in C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local too.

Comment: i have uninstalled it but not removed the .meteor folder manually . is it necessary ?

Comment: not sure, but it works for me :)

Comment: not worked for me, now its giving this error,
> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)